# Bootstrap responsive rows without scaffolding?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I'm suppose to be building a webpage that's around `460px` in width that has 2 columns. Like this:

```
| TITLE OF AN ARTICLE ....       | DATEOFARTICLE |
```

Todo this I've used:

```
<div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
         <div className="col-sm-8">NAME OF ARTICLE</div>
         <div className="col-sm-4">JUNE 6</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

But columns scaffold at `760PX` instead of shrinking down e.g at `760PX` it looks like this with plenty of room:

```
| TITLE OF AN ARTICLE ....           |                    DATEOFARTICLE |
```

But when it the width goes `< 760px` it looks scaffolds and ends up looking like this:

```
| TITLE OF AN ARTICLE ....               WHITESPACE?!             |
| DATEOFARTICLE                          WHITESPACE?!             |
```

Their is a whole heap of whitespace. Is their a way to make bootstrap not scaffold?

So basically instead of scaffolding, like the above example, I'd want it to shrink down to look this:

```
| TITLE OF AN ARTICLE ....       | DATEOFARTICLE |
```

#### Edit 1:

I changed my code to use `container-fluid` and it still does the same thing:

```
<div className="container-fluid">
   <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-9 col-md-6">
             Name...
        </div>

        <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-6">
             Jan 7
         </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the extra small classes `col-xs-*`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-8">NAME OF ARTICLE</div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">JUNE 6</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zo8d93yq/